# Spring integration: When do we need a specific outbound or inbound gateways

Tags: spring-integration

I have a question on spring integration gateways.
As I read from documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#gateway we have a general purpose gateway.

So, I am failing to understand the reasons to build any specific outbound or inbound gateways for new integrations. Are there any specific reasons to go with developing custom gateways?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Kalyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@MessagingGateway` (`<gateway>`) represents a POJI adapter to the Messaging subsystem, where your original code doesn't care about internals and just deals with target domain. That's a type of in-application integration.

When you need to interact with external world (or some specific internal protocol, e.g. Spring Application Events), you still need to adapt it somehow to your Messaging subsystem. For this purpose we have `inbound` gateways/adapters to receive data/events/packages/messages from the external system/protocol and `outbound` gateways/adapters to transform messages to protocol-specific entities and send there.

The gateway is two-way request/reply abstraction. The adapter only one-way: only to receive or only to send.

You can find some Gateway explanation in the [EIP Book](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessagingGateway.html).

Most popular protocols are covered in Spring Integration, e.g. HTTP, AMQP, JMS, WebSockets, JDBC, Mail etc.

You need custom gateway (inbound or outbound), if there is a desired protocol adapters implementation in Spring Integration.

But, yeah, don't mix  `@MessagingGateway` on simple interface with the `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` (inbound) or `SftpMessageHandler` (outbound) gateways, for example.

Comment: Thanks Artem. So, if I understood it right, the difference between following @MessagingGateway and protocol specific gateways is to have clean domain separation.

Comment: Actually, true. Just read more docs, e.g. Spring Integration in Action: https://www.manning.com/books/spring-integration-in-action

Comment: yeah!! I was trying to select vote. But missed the "tick" mark. Thanks again.